# В какой системе счисления файл?

Tags: linux, c, hex

Должен быть hex шестандцатиричный. Похож на него? Никак не могу понять как читать его и в какой он кодировке.
Вот кусок из него:

```
xxd /tmp/TTSCOF00.IMG | more
00000000: ca0a ffff ffff 5cc4 ff02 3002 1703 1222  ......\...0...."
00000010: 2003 0222 0417 0312 2220 0302 1206 1703   .."...." ......
00000020: 1222 2003 0257 0717 0312 2220 0302 4509  ." ..W...." ..E.
00000030: 1703 1222 2003 0237 1117 0312 2220 0302  ..." ..7...." ..
00000040: 2313 1703 1222 2003 0214 1517 0312 2220  #...." ......."
00000050: 0302 0117 1703 1222 2003 0251 1817 0312  ......." ..Q....
00000060: 2220 0302 3820 1703 1222 2003 0201 2217  " ..8 ..." ...".
00000070: 0312 2220 0302 5223 1703 1222 2003 0244  .." ..R#..." ..D
00000080: 2517 0312 2220 0302 3027 1703 1222 2003  %..." ..0'..." .
00000090: 0221 2917 0312 2220 0302 1131 1703 1222  .!)..." ...1..."
000000a0: 2003 0257 3217 0312 2220 0302 4934 1703   ..W2..." ..I4..
000000b0: 1222 2003 0241 3617 0312 2220 0302 2838  ." ..A6..." ..(8
000000c0: 1703 1222 2003 0223 4017 0312 2220 0302  ..." ..#@..." ..
000000d0: 0242 1703 1222 2003 0253 4317 0312 2220  .B..." ..SC..."
000000e0: 0302 4945 1703 1222 2003 0231 4717 0312  ..IE..." ..1G...
000000f0: 2220 0302 2049 1703 1222 2003 0210 5117  " .. I..." ...Q.
00000100: 0312 2220 0302 5952 1703 1222 2003 0255  .." ..YR..." ..U
00000110: 5417 0312 2220 0302 5256 1703 1222 2003  T..." ..RV..." .
00000120: 0230 5817 0312 2220 0302 2000 1803 1222  .0X..." .. ...."
00000130: 2003 0202 0218 0312 2220 0302 5703 1803   ......." ..W...
00000140: 1222 2003 0252 0518 0312 2220 0302 3207  ." ..R...." ..2.
00000150: 1803 1222 2003 0232 0918 0312 2220 0302  ..." ..2...." ..
00000160: 3111 1803 1222 2003 0204 1318 0312 2220  1...." ......."
00000170: 0302 0815 1803 1222 2003 0202 1718 0312  ......." .......
00000180: 2220 0302 0819 1803 1222 2003 0211 2118  " ......." ...!.
00000190: 0312 2220 0302 0223 1803 1222 2003 0203  .." ...#..." ...
000001a0: 2518 0312 2220 0302 0227 1803 1222 2003  %..." ...'..." .
000001b0: 0201 2918 0312 2220 0302 5530 1803 1222  ..)..." ..U0..."
000001c0: 2003 0231 3218 0312 2220 0302 3634 1803   ..12..." ..64..
000001d0: 1222 2003 0242 3618 0312 2220 0302 4038  ." ..B6..." ..@8
000001e0: 1803 1222 2003 0249 4018 0312 2220 0302  ..." ..I@..." ..
000001f0: 3542 1803 1222 2003 0242 4418 0312 2220  5B..." ..BD..."
00000200: 0302 5146 1803 1222 2003 0239 4818 0312  ..QF..." ..9H...
00000210: 2220 0302 4450 1803 1222 2003 0233 5218  " ..DP..." ..3R.
```

Comment: `hex шестандцатиричный` это способ представления данных для человека, к формату данных оно отношения не имеет

Comment: сама программа `xxd` решает как данные показать. попробуйте ключ `xxd -bits`. Это как раз и будет система счисления файла.

Comment: Сейчас вроде двоичный. xxd -bits /tmp/TTSCOF00.IMG | more
00000000: 11001010 00001010 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......
00000006: 01011100 11000100 11111111 00000010 00110000 00000010  \...0.
0000000c: 00010111 00000011 00010010 00100010 00100000 00000011  ..." .
00000012: 00000010 00100010 00000100 00010111 00000011 00010010  ."....

Comment: так 16-ричная ситема содержит 16 цифр 0..f вот восемь столбцов это и есть данные, предоставленные в 16-ричной системе.

Comment: ВСЕ файлы двоичные.

Answer (score 1):

Используй программу file чтоб определить формат файла. Если не поможет - используй binwalk